# Web app running on Azure is not picking up and using an environment variable connection string (ASP,NET Core RC1)

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[Github link for reproduction.](https://github.com/mariocatch/connection-string-test)

I have an ASP.NET Core (RC1) application that works fine locally. The issue I'm having is that my connection string is not being picked up by my Azure app. I've asked similar questions to this, but I've narrowed down the issue on my end in [this app.](https://github.com/mariocatch/connection-string-test) Note, it requires an app on Azure to reproduce it.

Here's the issue I'm seeing.

First, my configuration is setup as such:

```
public Startup()
{ 
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    mConfiguration = builder.Build();
}
```

And EF7 is setup here:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<FooDbContext>(options =>
            {
                // I'm assuming it's failing here. 
                // I'm not sure how to debug it running on Azure. 
                // All the developer exception page shows is:
                //  500 Internal Server Error "An error occurred while starting the application."
                options.UseSqlServer(mConfiguration["Data:ConnectionStringTest:ConnectionString"]);
            });
    services.AddScoped<IFooDataService, FooSqlDataService>();
}
```

My `config.json` has:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "ConnectionStringTest": {
      "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=ConnectionStringTest"
    }
  }
}
```

And this should be overridden by the connection string I've setup in Azure:

[image: azure connection string snapshot]

When going to the Kudu SCM and looking at the environment variables on the Azure web app instance, I see the following:

`SQLAZURECONNSTR_Data:ConnectionStringTest:ConnectionString = my_connection_string_here`

I am assuming this is the class that is being used under the hood when my environment variable is used at runtime: [EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/configuration/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables/EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider.cs#L54)

Comment: Nice find with the `EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider`!

Answer (score 1):

Ok here's what I found, and this feels awkward.

It seems that you need to use `Data:{my_connection_string_key}:ConnectionString` everywhere *EXCEPT* in Azure. [This environment variable converter](https://github.com/aspnet/configuration/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables/EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider.cs#L65) will construct the proper connection string [using this format](https://github.com/aspnet/configuration/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables/EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider.cs#L18) automatically if the connection string is prefixed with `SQLAZURECONNSTR_`.

This means when you setup your connection string in Azure, you need to omit *EVERYTHING* except the key to your connection string. Do not insert `Data:` or `:ConnectionString`... simply use `{connection_string_key}` (refer to the above format) instead. If you include the entire format in your Azure key/value pair, the `EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider` will add another `Data:` and `:ConnectionString` around it, resulting in something like `Data:Data:{my_connection_string_key}:ConnectionString:ConnectionString`.

In `ConfigureServices(...)`, use the format that ASP expects:

`... options.UseSqlServer(mConfiguration["Data:ConnectionStringTest:ConnectionString"]);`

You can therefore locally use this for your local JSON, for testing in development/fallback:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "ConnectionStringTest": {
      "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=ConnectionStringTest"
    }
  }
}
```

Just make sure your Azure connection string has the middle part of that format (`ConnectionStringTest` using this example).

[image]

This will make your environment variable in Azure look like this in raw format:

`SQLAZURECONNSTR_ConnectionStringTest = {insert connection string here}`

And the `EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider` will strip off the Azure prefix string, and wrap your key in the hardcoded format: `Data:{0}:ConnectionString`

Comment: That's why I use 'regular' `AppSettings` in Azure instead of `ConnectionStrings` :(

Answer (score 1):

## Experiment Results

To augment your excellent answer, I did a local experiment to confirm that the `SQLAZURECONNSTR_connection_string_key` environmental variable becomes this configuration:

```
mConfiguration["Data:connection_string_key:ConnectionString"]
```

## Local Experiment

A local environmental variable emulates an Azure SQL Database connection string named `connection_string_key`.

```
PS> $env:SQLAZURECONNSTR_connection_string_key = "an azure conn string"
```

The following code dumps all the environmental variables and configuration sections to the page.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("# Environmental Variables \r\n");
        await DumpAllEnvVariables(context, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables());

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("# Configuration Sections \r\n");
        await DumpAllConfigItems(context, mConfiguration.GetChildren());
    });
}

private async Task DumpAllEnvVariables(HttpContext context, IDictionary envVariables)
{
    foreach (var envVar in envVariables.Cast<DictionaryEntry>())
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"{envVar.Key}"); // : {envVar.Value}
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"\r\n");
    }
}

private async Task DumpAllConfigItems(HttpContext context, 
    IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> sections, string prefix = "")
{
    foreach (var section in sections)
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"{prefix}{section.Key}"); // : {envVar.Value}
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"\r\n");

        if(section.GetChildren().Any())
        {
            await DumpAllConfigItems(context, section.GetChildren(), prefix + "  ");
        }
    }
}
```